# See Picture, securing shower floor to flange? Finish some kind of drain cover?

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture

Is that how its suppose to be? a caulking around the flange. I was shocked there was an obvious space for water to go down, unless there is something under the floor to stop the water. So I put caulking around it but it is not very professional looking. How do I get a drain on this? I hate looking down the pipe.

[image]

Comment: You took the cover off to take the picture right? *4" shower drain cover* (a little bit of standing water where the black grommet is, is normal)

Comment: @Mazura IDK how you can tell.  Maybe your magnifying glass is better than mine.

Comment: I'm not sure what, exactly, I'm looking at and where you put the caulk. This does, however, look exactly like the new shower pan I just installed with the exception that the recess in mine is square (with rounded corners) instead of round. Please [edit] your question to be much more explicit about what you're actually asking so we can get you a good answer - help us help you.

Comment: No, that's how it was when we moved in except the white caulking around the outer flange. Does aeyal fixture go on this somehow?

Comment: Does a metal fixture